# get all today's event where the date is stored as int

Tags: php, datetime

i need help on this code..Im a newbie on this thing

i would like to query a table to get all today's event where the date&time is stored as int (eg: 1510876800)

i tried it like this

```
$time = time(); 
$changedate=date("Y-m-d", strval($time));
$today=strtotime($changedate);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $xoopsDB->prefix('extcal_event') . " WHERE event_start='$today' ORDER BY event_organisateur ASC";
```

its not working because of the date in event_start have different time

How do i solve this ?

[image]

Comment: If you're not calling $time anymore time (no pun intended), you can delete it and have the second line like this:
$changedate=date("Y-m-d", strval(time()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing unix timestamps so that will only match on the exact same second of that specific day.

If you have a unix timestamp stored, first you need to convert it to a mysql `datetime` value and then you can get the date part of it:

```
... WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start)) = :today ...
```

Here the value you bind to `:today` should have the `Y-m-d` format.

Note that I have used a placeholder for your variable as you should use prepared statements instead of injecting values directly into your query.